# Parsing Bulky XML to load in DB

Tags: java, xml, postgresql, scala

I have bulky (~500 Mb) well-formed XML files, which I want to parse and turn into relational form.
Here are technologies of my choice

- **Postgres** DB (but I can use **MongoDB** if it gives any special benefit)
- **Scala** (so I can use any Java library too)
- Akka for concurrency (I would want to use all the cores)

I have looked around various solutions (pentaho, postgres XML data type and other Java libraries) but before starting I wanted to hear from someone who has done such work to know what **tools & strategies** were employed.

[Side note: I am a fan of functional approach]

Comment: Have you considered using an ETL? (Extract, transform, load). Using a XML  adpater, it may load all your data in DB (see "ETL tools" in Google)

Comment: My choice for XML parsing in Scala (it supports functional style programming): http://anti-xml.org/

Comment: Anti-XML does not appear to be actively developed. The most recent commits are over two years old.

Comment: @xav - `Pentaho`, mentioned in my question, is an ETL tool but what I learnt over time was that it's very slow (compared to coding and using other libraries). I would be interested if there is any other open-source ETL there for such a job.

Comment: @Venkat - I had researched and as Randall commented I found that anti-xml was no longer being actively developed and that is why I am here :)

Comment: @DevMaha: You're right, I understand. A few years ago I used "Squirrel" ETL which was open source but don't know what it became now...

Comment: @xav may I know how your experience was with this ETL tool, did you find it performant?

Comment: @DevMaha: I'm afraid it was a bit slow too...

Comment: many many many many years ago I had to deal with a bioinformatics dataset in XML that was something near the size of yours. I remember I've used some obscure experimental java library that could infer the table structure from the XML DTD, parse the XML and generate the CSV for each table. Despite it was a quite big file, there were something like 4-6 tables only. I was using mysql at that time. I remember that mysqlimport for CSV was the fastest thing I ever seen (like of course any other native DBMS import tool) to push this data into the DB. Not a pretty way to do the job, but fast.

Comment: I hope 10 years later you may find something easier and faster to do the job ;-)

Comment: Check out Pentaho Kettle, Talend Studio, CloverETL. Or write some simple Python/Perl/Ruby/whatever to insert it with the language PostgreSQL database adapter - that'll be faster, but potentially fiddlier. All those languages support streaming-style XML reading. (You haven't described the XML usefully, so it's hard to say more - is this just a list of records? Is it deeply nested? Is it uniform in structure or does it have several separate regions? etc.)

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. I a currently evaluating CloverETL; let's see how it goes. The XML I have, I would say, is not deeply nested, it has multiple region but it's not that complex. All I need is something that is fast